How much cash do ETFs keep in reserve for redemptions and buying opportunities?
If Vanguard NASDAQ 100 ETF (QQQ) has $300 Billion under management (AUM), then how much of that will they (or a typical index fund) keep in cash (for redemptions, buying opportunities, etc.)?

This really isn't a personal finance question. There is no universal answer, and the number isn't constant since it depends on what's happening with the fund. There may be a target for that number!; if so it will be in the prospectus if it's anywhere.

ETF is not a mutual fund. See this: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126592/understanding-how-an-etf-works?rq=1

I don't believe Vanguard themselves offer an ETF which tracks the NASDAQ 100, but anyway in general the question you ask can be answered by looking at the holdings information of whatever specific ETF you are interested in.
For example, Invesco do offer a NASDAQ 100 ETF, ticker QQQM, and its holdings page is here https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/holdings?audienceType=Investor&ticker=QQQM
At the very bottom you can find this:

 Cash
0.00%     -CASH-  CASHUSD00   Cash/Receivables/Payables   85470.13    0.00    Currency


You can download the whole thing as a spready and see that the total is just over 30 billion, which is why the 85k in cash rounds to 0.00%. So for this particular ETF the answer is 'essentially zero'.
Every other similar ETF will also offer this information.
